# Simplifying REST API calls

Tags: apex, callout, apexrest, httpcalloutmock

I'm new to Java programming and I'm trying to reduce the number of REST API calls I make in my program to better organize it and I'm not sure how best to approach it if the simplest way is to have a function return an object. Here is my following code and the sequences that repeat themselves:

```
public static Map<String, String> listGroups() {
HTTPRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint('callout:PrimaryEndpoint/');
HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
....
}

public static Map<String, String> listUsers() {
HTTPRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint('callout:PrimaryEndpoint/users');
HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
....
}

public static Map<String, String> listFiles() {
HTTPRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint('callout:PrimaryEndpoint/files');
HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
....
}
```

Since the JSON output of these calls are parsed differently, I'm not able to simplify these under a common function. How would this work to where I only have one function providing HTTPResponse objects to feed into my other functions? I'm not sure how Salesforce handles custom objects as function inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to pass serialized Body or String to functions?

Comment: No because I use a mix of serialized and JSON2Apex functions in the parsing

Comment: Have a look at [composite resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2017/01/simplify-your-api-code-with-new-composite-resources.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this any number of ways. One would be to have a method to do your callout and return a `HttpResponse`. You can then call this method to get the response. I'd also add some error handling in this method to check if you got a 200 response code.

```
public static HttpResponse doCallout(String urlPath) {

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req.setEndpoint('callout:PrimaryEndpoint/' + urlPath);
    HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);

    //do some error checking here
    return res;

}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I was not aware the HTTPResponse object could be natively invoked as an outgoing parameter.